# load one record with doctrine

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

What is the preferred way to load one record with doctrine?

I am using

```
$em = EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);
$dql = "select r from Rolle r";
$list = $em->createQuery($dql)->getResult();
```

to get a list of records.

I tried using

```
$dql = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('Rolle r') 
    ->where('r.ID = 14');
$rolle = $dql->fetchArray();
```

to get one record. Is this the preferred way?

If yes: I get the internal server error: Class 'Doctrine_Query' not found in ... on line ...

I searched for a file which contains the string 'Doctrine_Query', but I haven't such a file. So where do I find this class?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might use `getSingleResult()` instead of `getResult()`. It's documentet in [this](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/query-builder.html#executing-a-query) chapter of the doctrine doc.

Comment: with the documentation and your help my source looks now like this:

$em = EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('r')->from('Rolle', 'r')->where('r.ID = :id')->setParameter('id', $_REQUEST['id']);
$rolle = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleResult();

Comment: `getSingleResult()` enforces that the result must be unique. Is there a preferred way to load a single result without enforcing uniqueness, for example if your query matches a set of records but you only want to get the first one?

Comment: @WildWorx sure, check the [this doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#limiting-the-result) on the latest doctrine orm.

Comment: @Scube Thanks, just found an answer in another question that let me to a more direct solution. See my answer below, if you want to update your original answer for brevity I'll gladly remove mine. As the documentation suggests, `setMaxResults()` is an option, however `getOneOrNullResult()` is more direct as it returns the object itself whereas `setMaxResults()` returns the object within an array.

Answer (score 10):

I think you're looking for `getOneOrNullResult()`.

As scube answered, `getSingleResult()` also works however this method enforces uniqueness of the result and will throw a `NonUniqueResultException` if your query matches more than one record. It's almost a year since scube's answer though, it's possible that this was not the case at the time.

**Credit:** Cerad and m2mdas for their comment / answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9954834/1375030) that lead me to `getOneOrNullResult()`.

Comment: An important difference it's that getSingleResult will throw a NoResultException if no records are found

Answer (score 8):

As I said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348604/get-single-row-result-with-doctrine-nativequery/32169476#32169476), you shouldn't use `getSingleResult()` or `getOneOrNullResult()` to retrieve the first row, Because these functions throw an exception if the query return more than one result. To fix this problem you could add `setMaxResults(1)` to your query builder.

```
$firstSubscriber = $entity->createQueryBuilder()->select('sub')
    ->from("\Application\Entity\Subscriber", 'sub')
    ->where('sub.subscribe=:isSubscribe')
    ->setParameter('isSubscribe', 1)  
    ->setMaxResults(1)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getOneOrNullResult();
```