# Doctrine fetch one object directly not in array

Tags: symfony, repository, doctrine-orm

I have following repository:

```
    public function findClassPhotoByPath($path)
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('SELECT p FROM KSRGalleryBundle:Photo p WHERE p.category = :category AND p.path = :path')
        ->setParameters(array('category' => 'class_photo', 'path' => $path))
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getResult();
}
```

When I now use this repository-method the object is inside an array and I have to access it through $photo[0].

Is it possible to fetch the direct directly how it is the case by findOneBy()?

Best Regards,
bodo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `getSingleResult()`. Also [check here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md) for other options.

**Edit:**

If you don't want catch the `NoResultException` you can also use `getOneOrNullResult()` method.

Comment: Just be careful that one result is always obtained.  An exception will be thrown for no results.

Comment: @Cerad, Right. This can be avoided using `getOneOrNullResult()` method.