# Get single row result with Doctrine NativeQuery

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to get a single row returned from a native query with Doctrine. Here's my code:

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addEntityResult('VNNCoreBundle:Player', 'p');
$rsm->addFieldResult('p', 'player_id', 'id');

$sql = " 
    SELECT player_id
      FROM players p
     WHERE CONCAT(p.first_name, ' ', p.last_name) = ?
";

$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
$query->setParameter(1, $name);
$players = $query->getResult();
```

That last line returns a list of players but I just want one result. How do I do that?

Answer (score 108):

You can use `$query->getSingleResult()`, which will throw an exception if more than one result are found, or if no result is found. (see the related phpdoc here https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php#L791)

There's also the less famous `$query->getOneOrNullResult()` which will throw an exception if more than one result are found, and return null if no result is found. (see the related phpdoc here https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php#L752)

Comment: Nice, didn't even know about the getOneOrNullResult, but that is quite helpful!

Comment: If you want result in an array: `->getOneOrNullResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY)`

Answer (score 95):

Both `getSingleResult()` and `getOneOrNullResult()` will throw an exception if there is more than one result.
To fix this problem you could add `setMaxResults(1)` to your  query builder.

```
 $firstSubscriber = $entity->createQueryBuilder()->select('sub')
        ->from("\Application\Entity\Subscriber", 'sub')
        ->where('sub.subscribe=:isSubscribe')
        ->setParameter('isSubscribe', 1)  
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Comment: For anyone trying to use `SetMaxResults(1)` with a NativeQuery, that method is not supported [docs for version 2.3](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.3/class-Doctrine.ORM.NativeQuery.html).

Comment: One concern I have for this solution - if you're both asserting that there should be 0 or 1 results, but then swallowing the exception (via `setMaxResults(1)`) that should result in that assertion being false, then you might be masking a more insidious problem with your data model or application. Just FYI.

Comment: If you want result in an array: `->getOneOrNullResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY)`

Comment: Just a key difference here. For those who are confused on which one to use: `getSingleResult()` vs `getOneOrNullResult()`. `getSingleResult()` throws an error if no rows are found. but for `getOneOrNullResult()` a null value is returned!

Answer (score 18):

->getSingleScalarResult() will return a single value, instead of an array.

Comment: This is what I was looking for for my SELECT MIN(date)... query. Returns date without array. Thanks.

Comment: `getSingleScalarResult`  throws an exception if query returns more than one result.

Answer (score 5):

> I just want one result

implies that you expect only one row to be returned. So either adapt your query, e.g.

```
SELECT player_id
FROM players p
WHERE CONCAT(p.first_name, ' ', p.last_name) = ?
LIMIT 0, 1
```

(and then use `getSingleResult()` as recommended by AdrienBrault) or fetch rows as an array and access the first item:

```
// ...
$players = $query->getArrayResult();
$myPlayer = $players[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

I use fetchObject()  here a small example using Symfony 4.4

```
    <?php 
    use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Connection;

    class MyController{

    public function index($username){
      $queryBuilder = $connection->createQueryBuilder();
      $queryBuilder
        ->select('id', 'name')
        ->from('app_user')
        ->where('name = ?')
        ->setParameter(0, $username)
        ->setMaxResults(1);
      $stmUser = $queryBuilder->execute();

      dump($stmUser->fetchObject());

      //get_class_methods($stmUser) -> to see all methods
    }
  }
```

Response:

```
{ 
"id": "2", "name":"myuser"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fetch single row

```
$result = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->fetchAssoc($sql)
```

To fetch all records

```
$result = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->fetchAll($sql)
```

Here you can use sql native query, all will work without any issue.