# Symfony2 - Accessing entity from NativeQuery result key

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to generate a nativeQuery using a mixed ResultSetMapping that contains entities and scalar results. For example:

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();        
$rsm->addEntityResult('MyBundle:Evaluation','e');
$rsm->addFieldResult('e','id','id');
$rsm->addScalarResult('company','company');
```

when i {{dump()}} one of the query result elements, it looks like this:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => Evaluation {▼
    #id: 24
  }
  "company" => "INRA"
]
```

So in the result array, the company is identified with the "company" key while my Evaluation entity is identified with the "0" key.

My question is: is there another way to access entities defined in ResultSetMapping() other than with their numeric key ? like ScalarResults ?

Comment: what's your actual issue?...

Comment: Well my code works, but being forced to do something like $result[0] instead of $result['evaluation'] for example is very frustating. Let's say I had a more complex example with 10 different EntityResults, writing $result[8] isn't readable and the developer seeing this code will have to open the repository class to know which type of data $result[8] will contain. Moreover, if someone adds another entity result at the beginning of the query, all the previous references to the result will cause bugs because there will be an offset.

Comment: I've just noticed your comment, can you provide more complex example with 2 or 3 EntityResults? It's seems you've got some concepts wrong. When you fetch multiple elements, you do it to iterate through them with loop, each element should have the same properties. Accessing directly array element like this: $result[8] indicates there is something not right within the code.

Answer (score 0):

Number of results returned is connected with query, not the `ResultSetMapping` object.

Assuming you have used `$query->getResult();` to fetch data, you can switch to `$query->getSingleResult()` or `$query->getOneOrNullResult()` Keep in mind those methods throw exceptions when more than one result is available.

You also *(most likely)* need to update last line, and place everything under the same alias:

`$rsm->addScalarResult('company','e');`

Second param represents alias [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#scalar-results). Additionally simillar issues was covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348604/get-single-row-result-with-doctrine-nativequery)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This isn't the issue, I get more than one result in my query and it's fine! Though as I said in my post, the data I displayed (from doctrine's dump() function) only represents 1 element of the result set. This means that foreach result row I will have a $result[0] and a $result['company']. What I want is a custom key, something like $result['evaluation'] instead of $result[0], for code readability and maintainability